# Why this three js code not working from local computer?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am new to three js.I save [this](http://cytoweb.co.uk/3ds/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_lines.html) page as html from Firefox to my desktop.All related files(threejs,statsjs,helvetiker_bold js.detecterjs to my desktop) are saved successfully.But animation is not working and there is no error shows in firebug.Whats the problem with me? Earlier successfully saved and edited [this](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html) page

Comment: view source of what you saved vs the page online. the js changes html in runtime and browser saves whatever it is at that time, not the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View source of what you saved vs the page online.

The JS changes html in run time and browser saves whatever it is at that time, not the original file.

You can view source the website and save the html manually, then change all the paths to the included resources (JS/CSS files) and it should work fine.